# Cacheing an ActiveRecord Object that has_many through:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, marshalling, dalli

When I try to cache an `ActiveRecord` object that has a `has_many through:` relationship, I can't cache the object until I reload or save it.

person.rb:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :person_locations
  has_many :locations, through: :person_locations

  has_many :person_items
  has_many :items, through: :person_items
end
```

person_item.rb:

```
class PersonItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :item_id, :person_id

  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :person
end
```

item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description

  has_many :person_items
  has_many :people, through: :person_items
end
```

Console:

```
p = Person.create
p.items << Item.create
Rails.cache.write Time.now, p
=> false

#now if I save or reload p
p.save # or p.reload
Rails.cache.write Time.now, p
=> truthy
```

It fails at the `Marshal` step. So `Marshal.dump(p)` would fail with the `TypeError: can't dump hash with default proc` error.

If I just make `p` in memory (using `new` instead of `create`) I can write to the cache.

```
p = Person.new
p.items << Item.new
Rails.cache.write Time.now, p
```

Any idea why cacheing this `ActiveRecord` object is failing?

Rails: 3.2.14

Dalli: 2.7

Ruby: 1.9.3-p392

**EDIT**

See also: [Dalli: You are trying to cache a Ruby object which cannot be serialized to memcached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071299/dalli-you-are-trying-to-cache-a-ruby-object-which-cannot-be-serialized-to-memca)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a problem with `squeel`.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel/issues/232